# Цена вопроса

Tags: livewallpaper, android

Есть ли тут люди которые разрабатывали под андроид? Кто нибудь может мне сказать сколько можно взять за разработку живых обоев для андроида?

**UPD:** Я говорю про обои на заказ, т.е. человек лично для себя заказал обоину и мне ему её сделать нужно. Никакого маркета.

Comment: на фрилансе посмотри расценки, да и все зависит от сложности работы, потраченного времени

Comment: На фрилансе не нашел, по этому спрашиваю здесь

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что это не ресурс для поиска фрилансеров

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самая простая формула для расчёта: берёшь свою месячную зарплату, делишь на количество часов в месяце (~4 рабочих недели по 40 часов ≈ 160 часов в месяц), получаешь свою личную часовую ставку, затем оцениваешь разработку обоев в часах и умножаешь на свою ставку. Выходит примерная стоимость разработки.

Answer (score 0):

Максимум 2-3 доллара, если все будет удачно то за полгода накапает пара тысяч закачек. Если сильно повезет может и больше. В 99% случаев обычно получают несколько сот закачек.

Comment: 2-3$ за скачивание? это какие обои должны быть по такой цене?

Comment: Я же говорю максимум, вдруг камрад сподобится на че-то гениальное :)

Comment: Чем ниже цена, тем выше спрос!